# Appended <a> links not working in Chrome but works through Notepad++?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

So in popup.html I got some links that works when I load it into Chrome, but when I append some links using forminput.js; the links are appended and it does work when I launch it from Notepad++ but fails to work when I load it into Chrome, dropdown.js and createtab.js both works fine and has nothing to do with this problem, they contain logic for opening tabs and handling dropdown menu. Thanks

popup.html

```
<body>
<form id="aform">
  URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="URL" id="URL">
  <br>
  Bookmark Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="bookmarkname" id="bookmarkname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" id="formsubmit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="dropdown">Links</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a>
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="forminput.js"></script>
<script src="dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="createtab.js"></script>
```

manifest.json

```
    {
    "name" : "Links",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "links 4 u",

    "manifest_version" : 2, 

    "browser_action": {
        "default icon":"icon.png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

forminput.js

```
    function retrieveFormData() {

            var URL = document.getElementById("URL").value;
            var Bookmarkname = document.getElementById("bookmarkname").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
            var aTag = document.createElement('a');
            aTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Bookmarkname));
            aTag.href = URL;
            y.appendChild(aTag);
}


document.getElementById("formsubmit").addEventListener("click",retrieveFormData);
```

Comment: having said all that ... your code works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/4jffmwwz/ ... though, there's no `dropdown` so maybe one of `dropdown.js` and `createtab.js` are not "seeing" the changes made to the DOM by the "submit" button - without seeing that code, and the fact that adding links works as you want, the only conclusion is that one of the two files you haven't shown does NOT work

Comment: but everything works through notepad, what in Chrome causes the link to not function? I am not understanding the logic sorry, it is appending properly so I do not see why the form will not work

Comment: `but everything works through notepad` - what does this even mean? notepad is not a browser ... you are making dynamic changes to the DOM in the web page ... this is not the same as editing the source of the webpage and reloading it

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle link? https://jsfiddle.net/4jffmwwz/ ... see how it adds `<a>` tags exactly where you want them ... this shows that the code you've posted works as desired - it's the code you haven't shown that doesn't work

Comment: I see what you mean I will keep working on it, thanks

Comment: What *exactly* is shown in the [various appropriate consoles for your extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011) when you load and execute your extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup is a separate document (see [extensions architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)) that can't be navigated outside the extension's internal URL, which is chrome-extension://blablablabla/

You need to add `target="_blank"` attribute to all links or use [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) if you want to open the links in current tab (requires `"tabs"` permission or, much better, [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)):

```
chrome.tabs.update({url: 'https://www.google.com'});
```

Comment: you are amazing dude, appending target attribute woked, thank you!